# Are these the most powerful astra of each of the tridevas?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma, weapon

I have come across people who say the most powerful astra of Tridevas are:

Lord Shiva- शिवज्ज्वर अथवा माहेश्वरज्जवर(Shivjjwar or Maaheshwarjjwar)

Lord Vishnu- विष्णुज्वर(Vishnujwar)

Lord Brahmaa- ब्रह्माण्डस्त्र(Brahmaandastra)

Is there any statement in scriptures which explicitly mention about the supremacy of these astras over other astras of the same diety?